# PHP MySQl search engine advice

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I am trying to make a smart multi-language PHP search engine. For example I want to search for `samsung smarthphone` and the user type in `smasung smortphone` . Which is the best way  to extract this from  a 1 000 000 rows DB.
My idea was to select the rows where this REGEXP(for this example) matches

```
'[a-zA-z]*[smasung]{4,}[a-zA-Z]*' AND '[a-zA-Z]*[smortphone]{5,}[a-zA-Z]*'
```

This is selectinh me all the rows that has a word which contains at least 4 or 5 letters of the user input. But this means to run this regexp at every selected row and then levensteihn the match with the user input and save the best match. For 1 000 000 it is pretty slow. Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem, so i've exported all my important records to elasticsearch (NoSql and very easy to install). Next implemented a fuzzy search. (build-in)

```
{ 
"multi_match" : {  
    "fields" : ["product"],
    "query" : "smasung smortphone",
    "fuzziness" : "AUTO"
}
}
```